# Emulate 5.1 Surround Sound in Windows Media Player 12?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-media-player, surround-sound

I have the [VL Sound 5.1](http://www.neveron.ru/Default.aspx?type=myapps) plugin for Winamp which enables 5.1 surround sound emulation for stereo music files on Windows Vista/7. I'm just wondering, is there something similar for Windows Media Player 12 as I use it to watch movies/music videos and it'd be nice to at least get emulated 5.1 surround sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to speakers configuration in Vista/7, Playback devices, Speakers -> properties, Enhancements, check 'Speaker fill'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case On-board Realtek sound driver itself automatically splits the mp3 audio into 5.1 automatically even whatever media player i use .

So i request you to try update your sound driver software to latest version or OS upgrade.

Because while using XP the same sound driver produces the 5.1(i heard the the all frequencies of sound in all speakers ), but After OS Upgrade Vista/Windows 7 the updated sound driver works great , I can feel the difference in rear speakers and sub-woofer channels.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you guys know. The problems actually lie with Windows 7 HDMI and it's built in connection reading through EDID. All of the problems I have read about on the net all come back to EDID which is implemented as a form of Copy Protection.

Comment: It seems you're confusing EDID with [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection).